# What does this spear & carpentry square symbol mean?

Tags: christianity, heraldry

What does [this symbol](http://www.flickr.com/photos/glasgowamateur/8613518768/) (placed on the shield being held by an angel figure) mean? Is there any historical explanation for what it represents?

[image: Shield with a spear and carpenter's square]

Comment: The *square* is one of he well known symbols of Masonry. What time period is he sculpture from?

Comment: Its a 20th century cathedral addon.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The square and spear are emblems of [St. Thomas](http://saints.sqpn.com/saint-thomas-the-apostle/), the Apostle, aka *Doubting Thomas*.

He was well known as a builder in his lifetime, though I have my doubts that he participated in all the constructions listed on the site linked to above. This explains the builder's square in the emblem.

St. Thomas was stabbed to death by the spear represented in the emblem, c 72 AD.

This shield emblem might represent St. Thomas himself, or have denoted that the bearer regarded St. Thomas as a patron.

[Here is a link to a page of similar](https://www.google.com/search?q=symbols+of+st+thomas+the+apostle&rls=en&dcr=0&source=lnms&tbm=isch) symbols for emblems of Thomas the Apostle.